# Add suffix L to Scala variable which can be Int or Long

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, casting, long-integer

I have a Scala variable "sizeFile" which contains the size in bytes of the file created for each execution.

That variable is defined as LongType in a corresponding schema to create a DataFrame.

The thing is "sizeFile" variable sometimes gets the value in bytes of an int, i.e. 500.
Then when trying to create DF with that value I get the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long.

I know I can make that 500 as long type adding suffix "L": 500L, but how can I add this suffix to the value recovered in variable "sizeFile" ?

In pseudo code something like:

```
val fileSize = args.fileBytes
val fileSizeLong = ${fileSize}L

val schema: StructType = new StructType()
    .add("id", StringType, false)
    .add("fileSize", Longtype, false))

spark.createDataFrame(Seq(Row("identifier",fileSizeLong)), schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not like there's a magic keyword like `L` which can convert anything to a Long number! This `L` can be placed after a literal number, and that's a hint to the compiler for type inference. Type inference is done by some rules, when you do this:

```scala
val someNumber = 5
```

The compiler (based on the mentioned rules) decides that the type of `someNumber` is is Int, unless you explicitly hint the compiler that I want a long number, that can be achieved using either of these:

```scala
val someNumberLong = 5L // translated by compiler to val someNumerLong: Long = 5
// or
val someNumberLongV2: Long = 5
```

Back to your problem, the `val fileSize = args.fileBytes` is an integer, and you need the value as a Long number, so this is what you need:

```scala
val fileSizeLong = fileSize.toLong
```